# Using lodash nested array of object will be sorted out

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have the below dataset which needs to be sorted based on "AcctCode" and "SuperID" as below expected result using lodash.

Anyone help me how to sort out in Ascending order based on "AcctCode" and "SuperID" as below I have mentioned the expected result set. I have used _.orderBy(data), but it gives an answer for if we pass the whole array of an object not what I have mentioned below.

Example data set:

```
[
  {
    "100" : [
      {
        "id" : 1,
        "EmpId" : 100,
        "AcctCode" : "2002-00",
        "SuperID" : 2000,
        "ReportNo" : "10000"
      },
      {
        "id" : 2,
        "EmpId" : 100,
        "AcctCode" : "2001-00",
        "SuperID" : 2000,
        "ReportNo" : "10000"
      },
      {
        "id" : 3,
        "EmpId" : 100,
        "AcctCode" : "2000-00",
        "SuperID" : 2000,
        "ReportNo" : "10000"
      }
    ],
   "101" : [
     {
        "id" : 4,
        "EmpId" : 101,
        "AcctCode" : "2001-00",
        "SuperID" : 2000,
        "ReportNo" : "10000"
      },{
        "id" : 3,
        "EmpId" : 100,
        "AcctCode" : "2001-10",
        "SuperID" : 2000,
        "ReportNo" : "10000"
      } 
    ] 
  }]
```

Expected result as below

```
 [
  {
    "100" : [
       {
        "id" : 3,
        "EmpId" : 100,
        "AcctCode" : "2000-00",
        "SuperID" : 2000,
        "ReportNo" : "10000"
      },
      {
        "id" : 2,
        "EmpId" : 100,
        "AcctCode" : "2001-00",
        "SuperID" : 2000,
        "ReportNo" : "10000"
      },
      {
        "id" : 1,
        "EmpId" : 100,
        "AcctCode" : "2002-00",
        "SuperID" : 2000,
        "ReportNo" : "10000"
      },


    ],
   "101" : [
     {
        "id" : 4,
        "EmpId" : 101,
        "AcctCode" : "2001-00",
        "SuperID" : 2000,
        "ReportNo" : "10000"
      },{
        "id" : 3,
        "EmpId" : 100,
        "AcctCode" : "2001-10",
        "SuperID" : 2000,
        "ReportNo" : "10000"
      } 
    ] 
  }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map the values of `data[0]` using [**mapValues**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#mapValues) and then use [**orderby**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#orderBy):

```
const result = _.mapValues(data[0], items => 
    _.orderBy(items, ['AcctCode', 'SuperID'], ['asc', 'desc'] ))
```

It's not clear what the sort order for `SuperID` should be, so I've just set it to descending.

Answer (score 1):

With `lodash`:

```
var data = ... //per your definition   

// reduce over the key/value pairs (k,v) to produce a copy of the
// object but with values sorted as you described 
var obj = _.reduce(data[0],(acc,v, k) => {
    acc[k] = _.sortBy(v, ['AcctCode','SuperID']);
    return acc;
},{});

[obj] // to re-wrap the object into array so we get the output format you specified
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `lodash` using `sort` approach:

```
Object.values(arr[0]).sort((a, b) => {
    var aAcctCode = parseInt(a.AcctCode.split('-').join(''));
    var bAcctCode = parseInt(b.AcctCode.split('-').join(''));
    var aSuperID = parseInt(a.SuperID);
    var bSuperID = parseInt(b.SuperID);
    return aAcctCode - bAcctCode != 0 ? aAcctCode - bAcctCode : aSuperID - bSuperID;
});
```

Once [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) algorithm happens *in place*, your same arr will hold sorted values.